# How to download and host Next.js docs locally for offline use

Tags: javascript, github, next.js, localhost, documentation

I want to have the Next.js documentation available for reference when I'm offline, how do I download and host it locally. I wanted to clone the Next.js repo which has the docs within it but all the files in the docs folder are markdown files which  clearly won't create and serve a local server for viewing. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find some docs for older versions of Next.js on the Internet Archive.

Steps on how I did it:

1. Go to [Next's Github releases page](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases?q=v12&expanded=true).
2. Find a date of the version of the release that match the docs you want to view.
3. Go to the [Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/) and search for: "https://nextjs.org/docs".
4. Find a saved docs site whose date is close to the date you determined from step 2.

Here's one for v12: [Next.js v12 docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20221024234833/https://nextjs.org/docs/).